# Android Glide load the SVG image directly from the string

Tags: android, svg, android-glide

I want to load svg image in Android using Glide. In fact Glide support such job and I found a sample https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.6.0/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/svgsample/app. The question is that I want to directly load the image from a string which is in svg format, not from the svg file. The string is received from network or selected from sqlite. Can someone help me? I have searched a long time but it seems no one meet such requirement.

Comment: string in svg format?
are you saving image as base64 string in sqlite?

Comment: I save the string like this: 
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<ellipse cx="240" cy="100" rx="220" ry="30"
style="fill:purple"/>
<ellipse cx="220" cy="70" rx="190" ry="20"
style="fill:lime"/>
<ellipse cx="210" cy="45" rx="170" ry="15"
style="fill:yellow"/>
</svg>

Comment: Can it read an svg from an inputstream also?

Comment: But an inputstream means you will get the svg from a file(local or network). I don't know how to do this when it's saved in DB.

Comment: Here's how I've solved it [with AndroidSVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69174368/7023751)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.  You haven't been that clear on what part you are stuck on.

If you just need to get an `InputStream` from a `String`, then you can do:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(svgString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! In my code, I firstly load some string array(The string is just like what I commented above) from sqlite or network. Then I should parse them and load into some ImageViews.  I want to do this job using Glide and Android SVG lib, like the sample mentioned in my question. The difference is the sample load svg from file, but I want to load svg image directly from the string array received, and I don't know how to do this in Glide.

Comment: this doesn't works for me :( I get this error: `GlideExecutor: com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders registered for model class: class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`