# How do I load SVG String into ImageView

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, xcode

I have an SVG string

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 30" width="1200" height="600"><clipPath id="a"><path d="M30 15h30v15zv15h-30zh-30v-15zv-15h30z"/></clipPath><path d="M0 0v30h60v-30z" fill="#00247d"/><path d="M0 0l60 30m0-30l-60 30" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="6"/><path d="M0 0l60 30m0-30l-60 30" clip-path="url(#a)" stroke="#cf142b" stroke-width="4"/><path d="M30 0v30m-30-15h60" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="10"/><path d="M30 0v30m-30-15h60" stroke="#cf142b" stroke-width="6"/></svg>`

How do I render it on ImageView?

If this was .svg file, I can load it with Glide in Android or other SVG library but don't know how to get around it with this svg string.

Comment: You have to use vector drawable if you want to use the SVG file.

Comment: Find an SVG library that supports strings. Or, write the string to a file, then use an SVG library.

Comment: Finally found a libary https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/api_summary_11.html that supports loading SVG from string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out I think this may help you.let me know if this works

```
 String yourSvgFile = "Your svg file";
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourSvgFile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Glide.with(this).load(stream).into(yourView)
```

Comment: No, I'm getting the svg string from an API, not a file with .svg.

Comment: Replace "your svg file" with your string from api response

Comment: doesn't seem to be working:  ´val stream = svg.byteInputStream(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                Glide.with(this).load(stream).into(binding.img)´

Answer (score 6):

Accepted Answer does not really help me as Glide was throwing an exception asking to create a ModelLoader for type ByteArrayInputStream.Adding to the @Aweda's answer I used the AndroidSVG library as below.

Dependencies

```
//AndroidSVG
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'

//Glide (add only if you're going to use Glide to load the  image)
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

Code snippet

```
//SVG string content 
 val svgString =
            "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 60 30\" width=\"1200\" height=\"600\"><clipPath id=\"a\"><path d=\"M30 15h30v15zv15h-30zh-30v-15zv-15h30z\"/></clipPath><path d=\"M0 0v30h60v-30z\" fill=\"#00247d\"/><path d=\"M0 0l60 30m0-30l-60 30\" stroke=\"#fff\" stroke-width=\"6\"/><path d=\"M0 0l60 30m0-30l-60 30\" clip-path=\"url(#a)\" stroke=\"#cf142b\" stroke-width=\"4\"/><path d=\"M30 0v30m-30-15h60\" stroke=\"#fff\" stroke-width=\"10\"/><path d=\"M30 0v30m-30-15h60\" stroke=\"#cf142b\" stroke-width=\"6\"/></svg>"

//convert SVG string to an object of type SVG
val svg = SVG.getFromString(svgString)

//create a drawable from svg
val drawable = PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture())

//finally load the drawable with Glide.
Glide.with(this)
            .load(drawable)
            .into(yourImageView)
```

In case you do not want to use Glide and want to set the SVG image to ImageView directly, do as follow:

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: this one worked whereas the accepted answer didnt

Comment: People who are using AndroidSVG please note that I tried the approach of Bitmap to Canvas to AndroidSVGObj.renderToCanvas but it didn't work. But above approach worked. +1 for the answer